# Making web hosting plan payments?

Tags: business, freelance

I'm a web designer freelancer. I just started freelancing. What is the best process for web hosting plan payments? Do I sign up for web hosting plan myself using my credit card and collect payments yearly or do I ask the client to sign up for web hosting himself using his credit card? Please let me know what is the best option?

Comment: Are you planning to do a reseller hosting plan or are you finding a hosting plan just for 1 client? If you plan on doing a reseller account then you pay for the hosting plan and collect from the client (Usually monthly).

Comment: I just need it for 1 client.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with design?  Wouldn't this be better over on freelancer?  Just because you mention you are a designer you still aren't designing anything.  Your question is in regards to managing a server, which by some would fall under Webmasters.SE.

Comment: take it easy! ok?

Comment: How would you suggest me taking this easy?  You cycle through your three accounts over the length of time you've spent on GD.SE and continually ask questions that aren't in scope.  We've asked you before to merge all three of your accounts after we deleted two of them.  You frankly abuse the system and time here.  So I think I have taken it very easy.  If you do not want to comply with how this site works and merge all three of your accounts we can remove two.  If you keep posting bad questions you will just continuously get downvoted by the community and be auto banned.  Its up to you..

Answer (score 3):

Always always always have the client make these payments. It's fine if you are there helping them set it up but at the end of the day it's their site, they need to pay for it. Not to mention if you pay for it then you are stuck having to collect payment from your clients and all of a sudden you need to go into debt collector mode. It's beneficial to have the client pay for it for the client's sake as well as they can maintain access to their web account, and not the designer.